# Building Spark application with Maven fails

Tags: maven, maven-2, mahout

I have a spark program which uses Mahout and is written in Scala. I try to build it using Maven and have the following pom file.

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>classifier</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<description>My wonderfull scala app</description>
<inceptionYear>2010</inceptionYear>
<licenses>
<license>
  <name>My License</name>
  <url>http://....</url>
  <distribution>repo</distribution>
</license>
</licenses>
<properties>
<maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
<scala.version>2.8.0</scala.version>
</properties>
<repositories>
<repository>
  <id>scala-tools.org</id>
  <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
  <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
</repository>
<repository>
 <id>mvnrepository</id>
 <name>MVN repository</name>
 <url>http://mvnrepository.com</url>     
</repository>  
</repositories>  
 <dependencies>
 <dependency>
       <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
     <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
  <version>${scala.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
<artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
<version>0.10.1</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
  <artifactId>mahout-math</artifactId>
  <version>0.10.1</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
  <artifactId>mahout-mr</artifactId>
 <version>0.10.1</version>
 </dependency>   
  </dependencies>
```

.....

When I try to build it using Maven I get the following error message:

```
      Downloading: http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/apache/mahout/mahout-core/0.10.1/mahout-core-0.10.1.pom
 Downloading: http://mvnrepository.com/org/apache/mahout/mahout-core/0.10.1/mahout-core-0.10.1.pom
 Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/mahout/mahout-core/0.10.1/mahout-core-0.10.1.pom
 [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.mahout:mahout-core:jar:0.10.1 is missing, no dependency information available
 Downloading: http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/apache/mahout/mahout-mr/0.10.1/mahout-mr-0.10.1.pom
 Downloading: http://mvnrepository.com/org/apache/mahout/mahout-mr/0.10.1/mahout-mr-0.10.1.pom
 Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/mahout/mahout-mr/0.10.1/mahout-mr-0.10.1.pom
 Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/mahout/mahout-mr/0.10.1/mahout-mr-0.10.1.pom (7 KB at 4.8 KB/sec)
 Downloading: http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/apache/mahout/mahout-hdfs/0.10.1/mahout-hdfs-0.10.1.pom
 Downloading: http://mvnrepository.com/org/apache/mahout/mahout-hdfs/0.10.1/mahout-hdfs-0.10.1.pom
 Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/mahout/mahout-hdfs/0.10.1/mahout-hdfs-0.10.1.pom
 Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/mahout/mahout-hdfs/0.10.1/mahout-hdfs-0.10.1.pom (6 KB at 10.5 KB/sec)
 Downloading: http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/apache/mahout/mahout-core/0.10.1/mahout-core-0.10.1.jar
 Downloading: http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/apache/mahout/mahout-hdfs/0.10.1/mahout-hdfs-0.10.1.jar
 Downloading: http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/apache/mahout/mahout-mr/0.10.1/mahout-mr-0.10.1.jar
 Downloading: http://mvnrepository.com/org/apache/mahout/mahout-core/0.10.1/mahout-core-0.10.1.jar
 Downloading: http://mvnrepository.com/org/apache/mahout/mahout-hdfs/0.10.1/mahout-hdfs-0.10.1.jar
 Downloading: http://mvnrepository.com/org/apache/mahout/mahout-mr/0.10.1/mahout-mr-0.10.1.jar
 Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/mahout/mahout-core/0.10.1/mahout-core-0.10.1.jar
 Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/mahout/mahout-hdfs/0.10.1/mahout-hdfs-0.10.1.jar
 Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/mahout/mahout-mr/0.10.1/mahout-mr-0.10.1.jar
 Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/mahout/mahout-hdfs/0.10.1/mahout-hdfs-0.10.1.jar (26 KB at 18.4 KB/sec)
 Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/mahout/mahout-mr/0.10.1/mahout-mr-0.10.1.jar (1378 KB at 655.4 KB/sec)
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: 12.254 s
 [INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-29T14:53:38-07:00
 [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/491M
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project classifier: Could not resolve   dependencies for project com.collabware:classifier:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.mahout:mahout-core:jar:0.10.1 in scala-tools.org (http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases) -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR]
```

I wonder to know why maven can't download the mahout files from mvnrepository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.mahout/mahout-core we can see that the latest release of mahout-core was 0.9. The mahout project dependencies have changed somewhat, you may wish to check the updated mahout documentation ( https://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/quickstart.html ).